# find usercontrol that a control resides in

Tags: winforms, controls, findcontrol

I know that if I have a control, I can do controlobj.FindForm to get a handle on the form it resides in. but is there a similar method to find out the UserControl that a control is in?

thanks

nat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up recursing my way up the parent tree until I hit a usercontrol